# Marklogic search inside array or objects and return only matching array items (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, marklogic

Is it possible to search across documents but only search using specific properties inside the array elements? Furthermore is it possible for the results to only contain the matching array elements and not the whole document (as other array elements in the same document may not match).

Example: given a JSON Marklogic document 

`{
    "name": "aName",
    "children": [{
        "name": "A",
        "target": {
            "min": 2,
            "max": 10
        }
    },{
        "name": "B",
        "target": {
            "min": 22,
            "max": 32
        }
    },{
        "name": "C",
        "target": {
            "min": 4,
            "max": 7
        }
    }]
}`

I only want to match `children` where `target.min` < 5 and `target.max` > 5.

In this case only `children[0]` and `children[2]` will match. How do I then specify a query to return only:

`[
    {
        "name": "A",
        "target": {
            "min": 2,
            "max": 10
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "C",
        "target": {
            "min": 4,
            "max": 7
        }
    }
]`

How do I construct the relevant query. N.B. I'd prefer server side javascript or Node.js implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Node.js, take a look at queryBuilder.extract or search response transformations to see if either of those meet your needs. Both topics are discussed under here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_24160.

In SJS, the jsearch mapper and reducer hook provides similar capabilities. See the following topic on "Transforming Results with Map and Reduce": http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/javascript#id_49222.

Comment: Thanks @kcoleman. I'm looking at map/reduce - it's probably the best I have now.
I must say this feels rather inefficient though. I can specify something like `cts.pathRangeQuery("children[*].target.min", "<",5)` and use it as part of a jsearch query. Then I have to then perform similar check inside the map/reduce function. Would be nice if I could just scope my query to only return results on on a certain level (like http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_87231)

Comment: Interestingly I can use `.map({snippet: true})` to find exactly where in the document the matches occur, then again I'd have to run other queries to fetch those parts of the matching docs.

Comment: I am confused about what you think you can do with structured query that you cannot do with these other interfaces. Structured query is quite literally nothing but syntactic sugar on top of cts:query. The goal of all the search interfaces is to find documents that match your query, and we provide some hooks for you to transform the matches as required, as well as some default options, like snippeting.

Comment: Okay, clearly I'm failing to communicate the specific problem I'm trying to solve. But anyway thanks for all your help, you've clarified a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In MarkLogic 9, you could use TDE to project a row for each child with the min and max values and use an Optic query with the comparisons.

Right now, Optic isn't available for Node.js, but that's planned.

In MarkLogic 8, the best approach would be to model each child as a separate document and create a range index on the min and max.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks yes it helps. I'm using marklogic 9. But at this moment it seems the best idea would be to have children as individual documents. Otherwise everything else becomes very complex.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var a = {
    "name": "aName",
    "children": [{
        "name": "A",
        "target": {
            "min": 2,
            "max": 10
        }
    },{
        "name": "B",
        "target": {
            "min": 22,
            "max": 32
        }
    },{
        "name": "C",
        "target": {
            "min": 4,
            "max": 7
        }
    }]
};

var b = [];

for(var i of a.children){
if(i.target.min < 5 && i.target.max > 5){
 b.push(i);
}

}

console.log(b);
```

Comment: This is pure javascript, which is fine for small arrays. The question I'm asking is how to do it via Marklogic, whereby I may have thousands of JSON documents. I'm guessing there should be a type of query which can achieve this. Anyway, thanks for your answer.